# Giving write permissions to a program

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

I've written a Python program with some UI and froze it using PyInstaller. The program writes to an xml document in the same directory, but not all of the users on the network have write permissions to this file. Rather than give everyone permissions to write to this file, is there a way to set the program's permissions to enable it to write there? That way regardless of who runs it the program will write to the xml, but any user who didn't originally have write permissions won't be able to go manually change any of the data in the file.

Comment: At least on Windows, you can change process execute permissions so it can run as System, Admin, User, Unknown, etc, but these are examples of virus tests. You can find some examples in vxheaven or even here in StackOverflow.
In my opinion, programs should stay as the process they are and give the process the permissions the account has and give network folder user permissions.
Giving a process certain power to take possession to run as certain "User" when he is not "User" shouldn't be a good practice

Answer (score 1):

A stated by @c_str in the comments you can run the process as another user on windows.

On Linux you can also use setuid and setguid to let process have his owner´s permission instead of runner user permissions.

Even though this works, both methods are questionable as stated by @c_str in the comments above.